# How can I edit the column for newtcolorbox?

Tags: environments

How can I fix the below code to be able to edit the text/contents of the right-hand "Grade" column? The current code from a Latex template only permits me to edit the contents of the "Title" column.

[image: Title and column table]

I currently have the following code for the colorbox and newenvironment:

```
  \newtcolorbox{prob}[1]{
% Set box style
    sidebyside,
    sidebyside align=top,
% Dimensions and layout
    width=\textwidth,
    toptitle=2.5pt,
    bottomtitle=2.5pt,
    righthand width=0.25\textwidth,
% Coloring
    colbacktitle=gray!30,
    coltitle=black,
    colback=white,
    colframe=black,
% Title formatting
    title={
        #1 \hfill Grade:\hspace*{0.14\textwidth}
    },
    fonttitle=\large\bfseries
}

\newenvironment{problem}[1]{
    \begin{prob}{#1}
}
{
   
    \end{prob}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Try with `\begin{problem}{Title} Hello \tcblower Bye \end{problem}`. The stuff after `\tcblower` will be placed to the right of the dashed line when `sidebyside` is used.

Comment: @JasperHabicht That works, thank you!

Comment: @JasperHabicht would you like to add an answer?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Posted it and improved the code a bit =)

Comment: @JasperHabicht Upvoted! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In `tcolorbox`es that are split for example using the `sidebyside` option, you can use `\tcblower` to move into the other part of the split body of the box.

You could also adjust the definition of `title` a bit, so that the right part has actually the same width as the relevant part of the split box body.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% needed because \textwidth changes inside the box.
\newlength{\bodytextwidth}
\setlength{\bodytextwidth}{\textwidth}

\newtcolorbox{prob}[1]{
% Set box style
    sidebyside,
    sidebyside align=top,
% Dimensions and layout
    width=\textwidth,
    toptitle=2.5pt,
    bottomtitle=2.5pt,
    righthand width=0.25\bodytextwidth,
% Coloring
    colbacktitle=gray!30,
    coltitle=black,
    colback=white,
    colframe=black,
% Title formatting
    title={
        #1 \hfill \makebox[0.25\bodytextwidth][l]{Grade:}
    },
    fonttitle=\large\bfseries
}

\newenvironment{problem}[1]{
    \begin{prob}{#1}
}{
    \end{prob}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}{Title} Hello \tcblower Bye \end{problem}

\end{document}
```

[image]